# Extract ALL e-mails from GMAIL, GROUP and SORT by frequency contacted

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail, google-docs

I want to extract all e-mail addresses from GMAIL and GROUP and SORT by the email address. The result is a sorted list of email addresses I contact the most.

After some Googling

- I have tried to export contacts (there is an option to select most contacted) - but this resulted in 20 most contacted. Does seem Gmail is counting ...
- There is a script by labnol that exports ALL e-mail adresses ... but this is rather slow & does not do the count

question: How can I extract all e-mail addresses from GMAIL and GROUP and SORT by the email address?

Would an export to IMAP work (and count from there)? or is there a smarter way

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. You can indeed extract headers (just headers, you don't need the full message body) from IMAP.
2. You can use the Gmail API. If you want to count who sends you messages, something like this should work.

Sample code using Gmail API in Python

```
# Retrieve a page of threads
threads = gmail_service.users().threads().list(userId='me',fields='threads(id)').execute()

# Print ID for each thread
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(depth=5)
if threads['threads']:
  for thread in threads['threads']:
    print 'Thread ID: %s has messages from senders:' % (thread['id'])
    t = gmail_service.users().threads().get(userId='me',id=thread['id'],fields='messages/payload/headers').execute()
    for msg in t['messages']:
      for header_from in [v for v in msg['payload']['headers'] if v['name'] == 'From']:
      # There should be only one, but sometimes From is missing
        from_field_val = header_from['value']
        print from_field_val
        # TODO Extract email address and increment count
```

https://gist.github.com/regisd/3b4733e974483d7994fe